# Editing registry values breaks entire system

Tags: c, registry, assertion

I'm having some troubles making a program that needs to edit some registry values NOT brick my entire pc. So below is the code that runs before the error also below. I have confirmed that manually editing the registry values works, but for some reason, this bricks my entire pc (I'm using a VM to demonstrate)

```
void startBCPE(DWORD SSIP, DWORD ST, DWORD SP, char CL[20]) {
    //Sets registery values for BCPE 
    HKEY key;
    RegOpenKeyExA(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SYSTEM\\Setup", 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &key);
    if (RegSetValueExA(key, "SystemSetupInProgress", 0, REG_DWORD, (LPBYTE)&SSIP, sizeof((LPBYTE)&SSIP)) != ERROR_SUCCESS || 
        RegSetValueExA(key, "SetupType", 0, REG_DWORD, (LPBYTE)&ST, sizeof((LPBYTE)&ST)) != ERROR_SUCCESS ||
        RegSetValueExA(key, "SetupType", 0, REG_DWORD, (LPBYTE)&ST, sizeof((LPBYTE)&ST) != ERROR_SUCCESS ||
        RegSetValueExA(key, "SetupPhase", 0, REG_DWORD, (LPBYTE)&SP, sizeof((LPBYTE)&SP)) != ERROR_SUCCESS ||
        RegSetValueExA(key, "CmdLine", 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)&CL, sizeof(CL)) != ERROR_SUCCESS)) {
        printf("error"); //runs if any above instruction results in an error, THIS CODE DOES NOT RUN
    }
    
    RegCloseKey(key);
    return;
}
```

so after the code runs you can't run anything as admin and the computer will not sign you in if you log out or restart.

Edit: hello I am back with some new info, It appears that the registry values its been writing are corrupted or something because CMDline is "8}-"

Comment: The first parameter to `printf` is supposed to be a format string.

Comment: What do you want to print with these wrong `printf` calls? Please [edit] your question to explain. Enable compiler warnings and fix the problems. You should check the return value of all functions, e.g. `RegOpenKeyExA` will return a value of type `LSTATUS` where `ERROR_SUCCESS` means success and everything else means that an error occurred.

Comment: *`printf("error"); //runs if any above instruction results in an error, THIS CODE DOES NOT RUN`*  And how do you know it doesn't run?

Comment: This edited code can hardly show the debug assertion.

Comment: I suggest you don't have one huge condition, but execute each `RegSetValueExA` separately and print the result. With your code you can only know that at least one of the `RegSetValueExA` doesn't return `ERROR_SUCCESS`.

Comment: Also if this bricks the windows installation proceed as follows, but only once you've corrected your code as mentioned in my previous comment and make sure all `RegSetValueExA` return ``ERROR_SUCCESS`. 1. modify the registry manually. 2. run your program. 3. Check if the modidied registry entries contain what you expect.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Because i ran it on a VM and it didn't print that

Comment: @Jabberwocky none of the code produces any errors (I found out that assertion error was due to another issue in my code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
RegSetValueExA(key, "CmdLine", 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)&CL, sizeof(CL));
```

`sizeof(CL)` is not the length of your string but it's the size of a pointer on your platform (either 4 or 8 in your case).

Nor is `sizeof(CL)` 20 as the  `char CL[20]` declaration might suggest. In this context `char CL[20]` ist strictly equivalent this `char *CL`.

Also `(LPBYTE)&CL` is wrong, you don't want the address of the pointer, you want the address of your data, you need `(LPBYTE)CL` (without the `&`). `CL` is alsready the pointer do your data.

So you're basically writing some garbage into the `Cmdline` value of the  `SYSTEM\\Setup` key in the registry, which might very well mess up Windows.

So you want this:

```
RegSetValueExA(key, "CmdLine", 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)CL, strlen(CL) + 1);
```

The `+ 1` is for taking into account the string null terminator.

Read carefully the the `lpData` and the `cbData` sections of the [`RegSetValueExA` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regsetvalueexa).

Comment: Ok so this correctly edits the values but it still results in me getting "the device is not ready" when I try to run anything as admin until a restart, I'm not sure why that is but I'm restarting the computer after editing the values anyway so its fine, also do you know why i need to use the & symbol for the dword values but not strings?

Comment: @SpiderBoy the 5th parameter is the _pointer_ to the data. `CL` is already a pointer and points to your string. `ST`, on the other hand, is not a pointer but `&ST` is the address of `ST`, in other words `&ST` points to `ST`. This is most basic C knowledge and you'd better get used to it.